# iOS -- trying to setup a dictionary of locks

Tags: iphone, locking, nslock

I have some code that takes an NSString as input and uses that string to create an object.  I need to make sure that it does not operate on the same string twice, e.g. if called from different threads, or even if the same thread tries to do it recursively.

I can make a start by making a dictionary of my initialized objects and grabbing that object if passed the same string again.  But this still leaves the problem of what happens when the object is requested a second time while other code is initializing it.

I see that Apple has provided me with the NSLock class.  I am at a loss as to how to apply it to my problem.  I see Apple lets me name my locks, but I don't see any way to access the lock with a given name.  I suppose I could make a dictionary of locks, but even that does not seem bulletproof -- what if two threads try to make the lock of the same name at the same time?

Can anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: Lock names are for debugging purposes only; otherwise the debugger would only be able to tell you that thread 2 was holding lock 0x02303342 and that's about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about making a static NSMutableArray with all your strings and synchronize your code.

Of course you need to initialize the array somewhere first ;)

Maybe like this:

```
static NSMutableArray* myArrayWithStrings;

-(void) someMethod:(NSString*) key
{
    @synchronized(myArrayWithStrings)
    {
        if(![myArrayWithStrings containsObject:key])
        {
            NSLog(@"Working with the key %@", key);
            [myArrayWithStrings addObject:key];

        }else
        {
            NSLog(@"Ignoring key '%@'. Already worked with it.",key);
        }
    } 
}
```

Comment: This works, though an `NSMutableSet` instance would be more appropriate.

Comment: Also, important: you should initialize the object OUTSIDE of the @synchronized block, otherwise every other thread will be blocked even if it would be fine for it to continue.